# How to install Excelsior JET on Linux (Centos 6.4)

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, centos, sudo, native-code

I have downloaded the 64-bit linux setup file **jet-1000-eval-en-linux-amd64-reg.bin** from the official site (**http://www.excelsiorjet.com/evaluate**) of Excelsior JET. After downloaded,I have execute the below process

$ cd /data/Testing

$ chmod a+x jet-1000-eval-en-linux-amd64-reg.bin

$ sudo ./jet-1000-eval-en-linux-amd64-reg.bin

While executing above command.It ask for License agreement.

ie .Do you accept EULA (yes/no)?: yes

After accept the license.I am facing the below issue..

```
Do you accept EULA (yes/no)?: yes
Enter destination path[    /data/Download/jet10.0-eval-amd64]: /data/Testing
/data/Testing/bin/uninstall
/data/Testing/bin/jc.cfg
/data/Testing/bin/jc.properties
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-dll.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-exe-normal.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-exe-splash.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-exe-ercp.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-exe-noreexec.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-rtlink.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/startup-rtdef.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/dummysplash.lib
/data/Testing/setup/updates/jet-eval-en-amd64-0-1.7.0_55.addon
/data/Testing/bin/jc.usg
/data/Testing/bin/jc_jit.usg
/data/Testing/bin/jc_ercp.fus
/data/Testing/bin/jc_tomcat.fus
/data/Testing/bin/jc.fus
/data/Testing/bin/jetcp
/data/Testing/bin/runhelper/runhelper.sh
/data/Testing/bin/runhelper/runhelper2.sh
/data/Testing/bin/libWizHelp.so
/data/Testing/bin/jetsetup
/data/Testing/bin/LaunchPad
/data/Testing/bin/jc.msg
/data/Testing/setup/updates/jet-eval-en-amd64-0.upd
/data/Testing/bin/jc.red
/data/Testing/bin/libscala-library.so
/data/Testing/lib/x86/rt.edf
/data/Testing/ideplugins/Eclipse/readme.txt
/data/Testing/bin/xpack
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/Hello.java
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/Sample.java
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/Sample.prj
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/Sample.class
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/Hello_dir/Hello.class
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/run.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/Absent/make_class.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/MyLoader.java
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/MyLoader.class
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/First/Foo.java
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/First/Foo.class
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/Second/Foo.java
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/Second/Foo.class
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/Classloaders/TheSameClassName/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/classes/GUIApplication$1.class
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/classes/GUIApplication.class
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/classes/GUIApplication.java
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/classes/GUIApplication.jar
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/jars/Extension1.jar
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/jars/Extension2.jar
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/lib/SampleJAR.jar
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/MultiCompBuild/CS_1.prj
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/MultiCompBuild/CS_2.prj
/data/Testing/samples/MultiComponent/MultiCompBuild/CS_EXE.prj
/data/Testing/samples/Hello/hello.java
/data/Testing/samples/Hello/hello.class
/data/Testing/samples/Hello/hello.prj
/data/Testing/samples/Hello/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Hello/JVMrun.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/attachCThread/test.c
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/attachCThread/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/attachCThread/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/attachCThread/run.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/MyClassInDll.class
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/MyClassInDll.java
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/test.c
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/clean.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/MyDll.prj
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/cMain/run.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaHello/test.c
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaHello/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaHello/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaHello/run.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaProperties/test.c
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaProperties/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaProperties/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/Invocation/JavaProperties/run.sh
/data/Testing/samples/TomcatCustomization/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/TomcatCustomization/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/TomcatCustomization/MyTomcat.prj
/data/Testing/samples/TomcatCustomization/MyBootstrap.java
/data/Testing/samples/SwingSet2/SwingSet2.prj
/data/Testing/samples/SwingSet2/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/SwingSet2/readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/InstallCustomization/hello.class
/data/Testing/samples/InstallCustomization/hello.java
/data/Testing/samples/InstallCustomization/build.sh
/data/Testing/samples/InstallCustomization/Readme.txt
/data/Testing/samples/InstallCustomization/install.c
/data/Testing/samples/InstallCustomization/uninstall.c
/data/Testing/bin/ImportResolver
/data/Testing/lib/x86/shared/libjetexpxdwh1000.so
/data/Testing/lib/x86/shared/libjetexp1000.so
/data/Testing/lib/x86/shared/libuninst.so
/data/Testing/bin/xlink
/data/Testing/bin/jc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/charsets.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.Turbo.properties.src
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/management/management.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/management/snmp.acl.template
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/management/jmxremote.access
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/management/jmxremote.password.template
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/psfontj2d.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.5.bfc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/cmm/LINEAR_RGB.pf
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/cmm/CIEXYZ.pf
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/cmm/PYCC.pf
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/cmm/GRAY.pf
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/cmm/sRGB.pf
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.10.bfc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/locales
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/calendars.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.11.bfc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/psfont.properties.ja
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/trusted.libraries
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/local_policy.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/cacerts
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/US_export_policy.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/blacklist
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/java.security
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/security/java.policy
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/sound.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fonts/fonts.dir
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fonts/LucidaSansRegular.ttf
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/jce.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.6.bfc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.6.properties.src
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.RedHat.5.properties.src
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.Turbo.bfc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.properties.src
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.11.properties.src
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.bfc
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/net.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/ext/sunec.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/ext/meta-index
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/flavormap.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libdcpr.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libmlib_image.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libnet.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libsplashscreen.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libjpeg.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libjaas_unix.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libnio.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libj2pkcs11.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libj2pcsc.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libj2gss.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libawt.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libunpack.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/headless/libmawt.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/jvm.cfg
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libkcms.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libfontmanager.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libzip.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libjava.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libJdbcOdbc.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libjawt.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libsctp.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libt2k.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libjsoundalsa.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/jetvm/libjvm.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/i386/libjsound.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/motif_LinkNoDrop32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/motif_CopyDrop32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/motif_LinkDrop32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/motif_MoveNoDrop32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/invalid32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/motif_MoveDrop32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/cursors.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/images/cursors/motif_CopyNoDrop32x32.gif
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/meta-index
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/logging.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/resources.jar
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/fontconfig.SuSE.10.properties.src
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/currency.data
/data/Testing/bin/rt/lib/content-types.properties
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLTH9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLHI9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXSCR9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXMIS9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXEND9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLVI9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLJA9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLEJ9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLDB9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXSQL9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXCRB9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXXML9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXL559005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/dynlookup9005.tbl
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXIMG9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLKO9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLEC9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXMIA9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXINV9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXSND9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXMNG9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLX29005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLEM9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXPKC9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXKRN9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXXXL9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLEK9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXRMI9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXAWT9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLEI9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXJCE9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXSSE9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLXT9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLET9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXL569005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXSWN9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXXWS9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLCH9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libxjitb_j9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXSEC9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/jetrt/libXLEL9005.so
/data/Testing/bin/rt/bin/unpack200
/data/Testing/pdf/jc.pdf
/data/Testing/readme/whatsnew.txt
/data/Testing/readme/readme.txt
/data/Testing/readme/report.txt
/data/Testing/THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt
/data/Testing/lib/x86/aj-rt-lowlevel.zip
/data/Testing/lib/x86/eclipsercp.startup
/data/Testing/bin/libImportResolverLib.so
/data/Testing/bin/xjava
/data/Testing/setenv
/data/Testing/lib/x86/shared/libgetenv.so
/data/Testing/bin/zip
/data/Testing/lib/extern-stubber.jar
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.5/catalina.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.5/version.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.5/startup.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.5/digest.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.5/tool-wrapper.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.5/shutdown.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.0/catalina.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.0/version.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.0/startup.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.0/digest.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.0/tool-wrapper.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/5.0/shutdown.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/6.0/catalina.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/6.0/version.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/6.0/startup.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/6.0/digest.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/6.0/tool-wrapper.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/6.0/shutdown.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/7.0/catalina.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/7.0/version.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/7.0/startup.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/7.0/digest.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/7.0/tool-wrapper.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/7.0/shutdown.sh
/data/Testing/lib/tomcat/TomcatSupport.jar
/data/Testing/bin/jc.tem
/data/Testing/setup/prebuilt/jet-eval-en-amd64-0-1.7.0_55.pjp
/data/Testing/bin/xuninst
/data/Testing/bin/xbind
/data/Testing/bin/renameprofile
/data/Testing/lib/x86/shared/libxdwhelper.so
/data/Testing/bin/xinst
/data/Testing/bin/libxinstres.so
/data/Testing/bin/xinst_lzma
/data/Testing/bin/libxinstres_lzma.so
/data/Testing/bin/JetPackII
/data/Testing/lib/x86/_libc.so
/data/Testing/lib/x86/_libpthread.so
/data/Testing/lib/x86/_libdl.so

Warning: JET Setup has failed to create profile due to the following reason:
Failed to determine compiler version.

In order to use Excelsior JET you have to run JET Setup and to create JET Profile manually.
Severe: Failed to determine compiler version.
Severe error: The installing of Excelsior JET 10.0 Evaluation 64-bit on your computer has failed due to the following error: Execution '"    /data/Testing/bin/jetsetup"  -show-welcome -ignore-jethome' failed - exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install 32-bit libraries on your 64-bit Linux to use Excelsior JET. So please make sure that the following libraries are installed or install them:

libc6:i686 libx11-6:i686 libxext6:i686 libxrender1:i686 libxi6:i386 libxtst6:i686

Answer (score 0):

$ yum install glibc.i686 libX11.i686 libXrender.i686 libXi.i686 libXtst.i686 libgcc.i686

Comment: Thanks zJay and Nikita Lipsky for your reply. When I execute your command .Still I am facing the issue **No package glibc.i686 available                                          ** Kindly help me out

Comment: @Nikita Lipsky i install jet success fully but i can't open the welcome page.can you help me